# Want to create a signurl for accessing private cloud storage bucket in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-cdn, gcp-load-balancer

I am trying to create a signedurl for accessing private cloud storage which contains static files.
I have configured http loadbalancer and enabled cdn on it. I have generated key and attached it to backend bucket.
I have followed each and every step mentioned in this document :-

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#gcloud

But while generating signed url it is not able to access the content of bucket. I am getting 403 forbidden error.

For creating key

```
head -c 16 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr +/ -_ > KEY_FILE_NAME
```

For adding the key to backend

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets \
   add-signed-url-key BACKEND_NAME \
   --key-name KEY_NAME \
   --key-file KEY_FILE_NAME
```

I am using this code to generate url

```
Gcloud compute sign-url \
"Http://Ip/" \
--key-name key \
--key-file keyfile \
--expires-in 30m \
--validate
```

But i am getting 403 error when accessing the generated url.

```
your client does not have permission to get url/ from this server
```

Comment: What does the error message say? Also can you update your question and add your code and any debugging details that might help us check the issue?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i have added the details, can you please help